# Copy a selected "custom" row in a Datagrid to another (WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

my problem is about a DataGrid, I want to copy a row to another DataGird in another form.
the DataGird looks like this : [image: capture]
on the click I want to show the selectedItem in the other DataGird but instead of the quantity (20) I want to copy the textbox as the user enter the desired Quantity because the 20 is the quantity in stock of the product, and the user should enter how many items wants of that product.

I tried event listeners it worked, I can copy the selectedItem to the other DataGird but I couldn't figure out how to copy the entered amount in the textBox instead of the textBloc (quantity in stock).
this is how it looked : [image: capture]

the click button code:

```
public static event EventHandler<ShareSelectedItemEventArgs> ShareSelectedItemData;
private void insertBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ShareSelectedItemData != null)
                ShareSelectedItemData(this, new ShareSelectedItemEventArgs() { ProductItem = (productsTable)productsDataGrid.SelectedItem });
        }
```

the code of the class ShareSelectedItemEventArgs :

```
public class ShareSelectedItemEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public productsTable ProductItem {
            get; set;
        }


        public int productId { get; set; }
        public string productLabel { get; set; }
        public string productUnit { get; set; }
        public decimal productPrice { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> productQuantityStock { get; set; }
        public ShareSelectedItemEventArgs() : base()
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are these ListViews or DataGrids? How do you populate them? Are they bound to collections, or are you populating them some other way? Please show C# code and XAML for how you populate your "grid views".

Comment: thanks for noticing me, I meant Datagrid
I'm using Entity Framework

Comment: In that case, how would you copy a row from one entity framework table/result set/whatever to another? Do that, and ignore the UI. Let the DataGrids figure out for themselves how to show the new table state. They'll do fine, I believe. That's always the WPF way: Modify the viewmodel, raise the proper notifications, and let the UI do its thing.

Comment: oooh I see I will give it try, thanks for the hint!